# Mapping static and dynamic views (and REST endpoints) in the same Dropwizard 0.8.5 app

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am new to DW (using 0.8.5) and am trying to implement a small DW app that acts as both a web app (serving a mixture of static and dynamic pages) as well as exposes a few REST endpoints for API clients.

Currently I have the app being served from the root context (http://localhost:8080 for local and http://dev.myapp.example.com for dev). I am trying to figure out how to make a static homepage (index.html) that maps to the root context ("/"), as well as a "contact us" style static page (contact.html) that maps to /contact.

Here's my desired URL strategy:

```
http://localhost:8080/         --> index.html (my static homepage)
http://localhost:8080/contact  --> contact.html (static contact page)
http://localhost:8080/app/*    --> dynamic web pages, using DW Views & Freemarker
http://localhost:8080/api/*    --> REST endpoints under here
```

I found [this blog](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/11/serving-static-assets-with-dropwizard/) which really confuses me, since it seems like there's no clear cut way of doing this in 0.8.5. Can someone explain the steps necessary to get this working? Preferably with code example or a GitHub gist? I think it would help a lot of people.

It sounds like I need to add the AssetsBundle, but I can't tell how I need to fully configure it or where to place the static HTML files inside my app. Thoughts?

**My best attempt thus far:**

1. Add `bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetBundle())` inside `initialize()`
2. Under `src/main/resources/assets/` place all static contact (`index.html`, `contact.htm`, etc.)

But what I'm struggling with is mapping the static HTML files living in `src/main/resources/assets` with my desired URLs, especially in such a way so that they do not cause conflicts with the dynamic views/pages nor the REST resources/endpoints. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `AssetBundle` and `ConfigurableAssetBundle` are **not** the way to go in DW > 0.8.x.

Instead, just use the [Dropwizard-Views bundle](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.7.1/docs/manual/views.html) exactly like you would for a dynamic view, just rename your HTML files to FTL or mustache files (e.g., `index.ftl` instead of `index.html`, etc.).

Comment: Does this still hold true for newer versions of DW, like 1.3? Because I've tried OP's attempts as it was outlined that way in the Docs and had the same outcome.